# New error MSB3073 when compiling test project

Tags: moles

When I went to rebuild the solution I get the following error:

> C:\Program Files\Microsoft Moles\bin\Microsoft.Moles.targets(79,5): error MSB3073: The command ""C:\Program Files\Microsoft Moles\bin\moles.exe" @C:\aSami\explorer\Content\FIGovCorp.test\obj\Debug\Moles\moles.args" exited with code -1002.

Nothing has changed in the test project, though the code has changed in the other projects in the solution. I have no clue what this error means, and cannot find anything relevant on the internet. Does anyone here have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This means the Moles framework encountered some sort of error, which returns code -1002.  I suggest executing the "clean" command on every project in the solution, and then "rebuild" each project, beginning with the dependency projects and working up the reference chain.  Doing this often resolves Moles compiler issues.

Otherwise, something has definitely changed.  It may not have been through Visual Studio.  A group policy change, file system changes, etc. can cause problems like this.